# Cannot copy item using mapped drive in Scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple PowerShell script that copies a file from a mapped network drive, if it's modified in past 1 day.

```
$source = "Z:\\"
$target = "E:\target"
$files = get-childitem $source

foreach ($file in $files) {
  if($file.LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).AddDays(-1)) {
     Copy-Item $file.FullName $target
  }
}
```

This script runs fine if I manually execute it.

If  I try to use a scheduled task, the copy does not run. I confirmed the script is running by having it make a directory.

If I instead copy from a local drive instead of a network drive, the script runs fine with a scheduled task.

Schedule Task is running as an Admin Account.

Script copying file from network drive runs fine manually but not via scheduled task. Script runs fine as task if copying from local but not network drive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the full UNC path rather than a network drive. (Network drives are a per-user configuration item.)

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I'll mark the question as answered in 4 minutes when it let's me!

Answer (score 1):

Map the drive as a temporary PowerShell drive...add the following as the first line of the script

```
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\sharename
```